# binary watch problem python solultion with bit manipulations

Tags: python

it's a leetcode problem about binary watch where it's required to find all possible times a binary watch can represent with a given amount of LEDs on([link](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/)) which i couldn't solve and checked solutions but can't grasp the logic behind the algorithm. if someone kindly can explain how this works it would be very nice and helpful. thank you

[image: binary watch]

```
class Solution(object):
def readBinaryWatch(self, n):
    
    def dfs(n, hours, mins, idx):
        #checking hrs, mins range, makes sense
        if hours >= 12 or mins > 59: return 
        #append some specific time if n == 0. not sure why.
        #guess it's cause only when n is exghausted we used all leds available
        if not n: 
            res.append(str(hours) + ":" + "0" * (mins < 10) + str(mins))
            return            
        #then completely unclear
        for i in range(idx, 10):
            if i < 4: 
                dfs(n - 1, hours | (1 << i), mins, i + 1)
            else:
                k = i - 4
                dfs(n - 1, hours, mins | (1 << k), i + 1)
    
    res = []
    dfs(n, 0, 0, 0)
    return res
```

Comment: What is the question? See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Chack it's

```
class Solution(object):
    def readBinaryWatch(self, n):
        
        def dfs(n, hours, mins, idx):
            #checking hrs, mins range, makes sense
            if hours >= 12 or mins > 59: return 
            if not n: #append some specific time if n == 0. not sure why
                res.append(str(hours) + ":" + "0" * (mins < 10) + str(mins))
                return            
            #then completely unclear
            for i in range(idx, 10):
                if i < 4: 
                    dfs(n - 1, hours | (1 << i), mins, i + 1)
                else:
                    k = i - 4
                    dfs(n - 1, hours, mins | (1 << k), i + 1)
        
        res = []
        dfs(n, 0, 0, 0)
        return res
    
n  =Solution()
print(n.readBinaryWatch(1))
```

**Input:**

```
n = 1
```

Output:

```
["1:00", "2:00", "4:00", "8:00", "0:01", "0:02", "0:04", "0:08", "0:16", "0:32"]
```

Comment: You should explain how your solution works.

Comment: lol thanks mate but i know what it does, i don't get how.

Comment: qustion don't use 'n  =Solution()' object.